# Dynamic embedded schema based on type

Tags: json, elixir, schema, ecto

I have a json/map field in database which can actually holds 3 kinds of objects based on type field define in table

so structure is like this

```
field(:type, :string) => user/player/admin
field(:object, :map) => embedded schema needed here. and it can be any of the three schemas ie user/admin/player
```

So is this possible I can have the flexibility of mysql and beauty/support of Ecto embeds.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually convert the json object to an embedded schema based off of the type. This can easily be accomplished with a transform.

```
defmodule EnrichedUser do
  defmodule User do
    defstruct type: nil, name: ""

    def new(record), do: %User{type: record.type}
  end

  defmodule Player do
    defstruct type: nil, name: ""

    def new(record), do: %Player{type: record.type}
  end

  defmodule Admin do
    defstruct type: nil, name: ""
    def new(record), do: %Admin{type: record.type}
  end

  def transform(record = %MyDatabaseUser{type: type}) do
    case type do
      :user -> User.new(record)
      :player -> Player.new(record)
      :admin -> Admin.new(record)
      _ -> {:error, :unhandled_type}
    end
  end
end

# Usage example
User  |> Repo.all() |> Enum.map(&EnrichedUser.transform/1)
```

This has the added benefit of decoupling your application logic from your database model. Your app will now pass around an EnricedUser.X struct which will server as the contract between services instead of the Ecto schema that will change when you make database changes.